# App goes stuck when click on firebase push notification in Killed state

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I was handling push notification data and then after call API based in push notification custom data. This will work fine when app is in Active and background state.

But when app is not running and then click on notification, I was able to get custom data from custom date But, API is not called and app getting stuck.

I checked in iOS 10 and 11, but not working

Handling push is like this.

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

            redirectToScreen(notificaiton: userInfo)

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        }

//Notify through Notification center
    func redirectToScreen(notificaiton: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  let dictPayload = notificaiton as NSDictionary

        print(dictPayload)

        if let type = dictPayload.value(forKey: "type") as? String {

            var dict = ["type" : type]

         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "handlePush"), object: dict)

   }
 }
```

**HomeViewController**

```
//Notification Observer goes here and call API
    let spinner = showLoader(view: self.view) // App goes stuck here and loaded process continuously, response is not getting  

    Alamofire.request(kURl, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).authenticate(user: R.string.keys.basicAuthUsername(), password: R.string.keys.basicAuthPassword()).responseSwiftyJSON(completionHandler: {
                        spinner.dismissLoader()

    })
```

Comment: Did u tried to cover all code in your `Notification Observer` with `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko Oh damn easy solution, You saved my day Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 4.0**

As per @TarasChernyshenko statement, I put Post Notification code in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` block and now it works fine.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "handlePush"), object: dict)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @TarasChernyshenko,

When you get callback from Notification Observer via `didRecieveNotification(_:)`, app remains in background. Any UI updates such as :

```
 let spinner = showLoader(view: self.view)
```

Must keep in Main thread queue as given below :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 let spinner = showLoader(view: self.view)
//other ui stuffs...
}
```